# PL/SQL update using CASE in join condition?

Tags: oracle, join, plsql, switch-statement, oracle10g

I have old Oracle 10g database and I need to write an update.. I write much better TSQL but my PL/SQL sucks so, I need some help.

I have 3 tables: Source, link and destination table. Because data in tables is bad, I need to use REPLACE/TRIM functions and CASE so I can make joins work.

However, this causes problems and I cannot figure out how I can write update after I have used CASE. I tried to use MERGE and UPDATE but no luck.
I wrote this SELECT-statement and I should work fine:

```
SELECT 
C.NAME, 
-- C.FLAG -- How I can update flag here?
FROM TEST.C_TABLE C
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT 
        CASE 
            WHEN LENGTH(TRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(ID, '-', ''), '&&', ''), '"', ''))) = 15
            THEN TRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(ID, '-', ''), '&&', ''), '"', '')) -- TRUE, because some rows causes problems...
            ELSE TRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTR(ID ,-9, 9), '-', ''), '&&', ''), '"', '')) -- FALSE 
        END ID,
                                                          NAME
    FROM TEST.B_TABLE
) B
ON B.NAME = C.NAME
INNER JOIN A_TABLE A ON REPLACE(A.ID, '&&', '') = B.ID
```

How I can "convert" this SELECT-statement to UPDATE or MERGE?

Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you express in English what the update needs to accomplish.  Based on your select query I'm not confident I understand the update requirements.

Comment: Add sample data from your tables and expected results after performing update. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53821762/edit) your question and add it in text format only, no images.

Comment: Consider that different DBs differ mostly in DDL, not in DML, and often `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` are pretty similar. Try writing it as you would do in TSQL and observe if there is any part that needs adapting.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hard to deduce your requirements here, but assuming that SELECT you have written returns a source of rows from C_TABLE then as long as you retrieve the primary key as well, then this becomes something you use as a source for the standard MERGE.

So you'd end up with something along the lines of

```
merge into TEST.C_TABLE c
using 
(
  SELECT 
  c.primary_key_column,
  C.NAME, 
  FROM TEST.C_TABLE C
  INNER JOIN
  (
      SELECT 
          CASE 
              WHEN LENGTH(TRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(ID, '-', ''), '&&', ''), '"', ''))) = 15
              THEN TRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(ID, '-', ''), '&&', ''), '"', '')) -- TRUE, because some rows causes problems...
              ELSE TRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTR(ID ,-9, 9), '-', ''), '&&', ''), '"', '')) -- FALSE 
          END ID,
          NAME
      FROM TEST.B_TABLE
  ) B
  ON B.NAME = C.NAME
  INNER JOIN A_TABLE A ON REPLACE(A.ID, '&&', '') = B.ID
) source_data
on  c.primary_key_column = source_data.primary_key_column
when matched then
   update set c.FLAG = source_data.?????
```

It's hard to offer more based on the information you've given us